# pandas set union not correct

Tags: pandas, dataframe, union

I'm writing the files just to check results. But my set union is not correct. I need to get the union of diagnosisFilters = [filterRDiagnosisM,filterTDiagnosisM,filterPDiagnosisM,filterADiagnosisM]
Currently returning 2 additional rows.

843786  ,  M   , 12.45  ,  15.7  ,  82.57   , 477.1

869691 ,   M   , 11.8    ,16.58   , 78.99  ,  432

Original file looks like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['842302', '842303', '842304'], 
               'diagnosis': ['M', 'B', 'M'],
               'radius_mean': [20.57, 17.3, 13.3],
               'perimeter_mean': [20.57, 20.57, 20.57],
               'area_mean': [206.57, 206.57, 240.57],})
```

[breastCancerDataReducedDimensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6ImW.png)

Below is my set union code.

```
diagnosisFilters = [filterRDiagnosisM,filterTDiagnosisM,filterPDiagnosisM,filterADiagnosisM]
diagnosisResult = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,how='outer',on=["id"]), diagnosisFilters)
```

I'll leave this here for context until I find a cleaner way to show this without the whole file

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce
import os

#FOLDERS
vf = './valueFilters'
df = './diagnosisFilters'
results = './results'
if not os.path.exists(vf):
    os.mkdir(vf)
if not os.path.exists(df):
    os.mkdir(df)
if not os.path.exists(results):
    os.mkdir(results)

#DATAFRAMES
my_csv = pd.read_csv('breastCancerDataReducedDimensions.csv')
radius = pd.DataFrame(my_csv[['id','diagnosis', 'radius_mean']])
texture = pd.DataFrame(my_csv[['id','diagnosis','texture_mean']])
perimeter = pd.DataFrame(my_csv[['id','diagnosis','perimeter_mean']])
area = pd.DataFrame(my_csv[['id','diagnosis','area_mean']])

#RADIUS
filterRadius = radius[radius['radius_mean'] >= 13.0]
filterRadius.to_csv(vf+'/q3_gte_13.csv',index=False)
#B
filterRDiagnosisB = radius[radius['diagnosis'] == 'B']
filterRDiagnosisB.to_csv(df+'/q3_B.csv',index=False)
#M
filterRDiagnosisM = radius[radius['diagnosis'] == 'M']
filterRDiagnosisM.to_csv(df+'/q3_M.csv',index=False)

#TEXTURE
filterTexture = texture[texture['texture_mean'] >= 18.0]
filterTexture.to_csv(vf+'/q4_gte_18.csv',index=False)
#B
filterTDiagnosisB = texture[texture['diagnosis'] == 'B']
filterTDiagnosisB.to_csv(df+'/q4_B.csv',index=False)
#M
filterTDiagnosisM = texture[texture['diagnosis'] == 'M']
filterTDiagnosisM.to_csv(df+'/q4_M.csv',index=False)

#PERIMETER
filterPerimeter = perimeter[perimeter['perimeter_mean'] >= 85.0]
filterPerimeter.to_csv(vf+'/q5_gte_85.csv',index=False)
#B
filterPDiagnosisB = perimeter[perimeter['diagnosis'] == 'B']
filterPDiagnosisB.to_csv(df+'/q5_B.csv',index=False)
#M
filterPDiagnosisM = perimeter[perimeter['diagnosis'] == 'M']
filterPDiagnosisM.to_csv(df+'/q5_M.csv',index=False)

#AREA
filterArea = area[area['area_mean'] >= 500.0]
filterArea.to_csv(vf+'/q6_gte_500.csv',index=False)
#B
filterADiagnosisB = area[area['diagnosis'] == 'B']
filterADiagnosisB.to_csv(df+'/q6_B.csv',index=False)
#M
filterADiagnosisM = area[area['diagnosis'] == 'M']
filterADiagnosisM.to_csv(df+'/q6_M.csv',index=False)

#RESULT
intValueFilters = [filterRadius,filterTexture,filterPerimeter,filterArea]
valueResult = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,how='inner',on=["id"]), intValueFilters)
valueResult.to_csv(results+'/NewResult.csv',index=False)

#CHECK RESULT - METHOD 1
diagnosisFilters = [filterRDiagnosisM,filterTDiagnosisM,filterPDiagnosisM,filterADiagnosisM]
diagnosisResult = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,how='outer',on=["id"]), diagnosisFilters)
diagnosisResult.to_csv(results+'/SubsetMResult.csv',index=False)

difference1 = diagnosisResult[~diagnosisResult.apply(tuple,1).isin(valueResult.apply(tuple,1))]
pd.DataFrame(difference1).to_csv(results+'/difference1.csv',index=False)

#CHECK RESULT - METHOD 2
originalResult = my_csv[my_csv['diagnosis'] == 'M']
originalResult.to_csv(results+'/OriginalResult.csv',index=False)

difference2 = originalResult[~originalResult.apply(tuple,1).isin(valueResult.apply(tuple,1))]
pd.DataFrame(difference2).to_csv(results+'/difference2.csv',index=False)

#COMPLETE
print('complete')
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! There's a lot of code here, and a lot of data. I suspect only a small amount of it is necessary to identify your problem, but helpers may have to sift through extraneous details. Can you please reduce this to a [mcve]? It'll help you to get a better answer, faster.

Comment: This may also help: [How to make a good `pandas` example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: had the whole code at the bottom for context. I have removed it from the post

Comment: I think now the pendulum has swung too far in the other direction. The [mre] should be reproducible; currently there's not enough to run your code. A good guideline: provide the shortest code necessary that someone can copy into their terminal and run, so they can debug. / Anyway, I don't see what the problem is—what's wrong about the fact that those rows are present?

Comment: added back for now. The issue is the rows should not be there it's outside the filter criteria.

Comment: So you want the intersection of the set, not the union?

Comment: I needed both but the union was where the extra entries where, turns out I was filtering wrong

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. the issue was not in the set operations. I had filtered incorrectly. so the input files where not correct. took me a bit to reverse why that was the case but in the end I needed to filter a filtered df but I filtered the unfiltered df instead.

```
filterRDiagnosisB = radius[radius['diagnosis'] == 'B']
```

changed to:

```
filterRDiagnosisB = filterRadius[filterRadius['diagnosis'] == 'B']
```